# How to change my code from multiple if statements to Switch Case statements

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have way too many IF statements, 
how do I convert my code to case style ?

here is an example of my code 
I have researched a lot I can't seem to get it working with case statements

```
function onEdit(e){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetBoutons = ss.getSheetByName("Boutons");
var sheetINV = ss.getSheetByName("INV");
var sheetList = ss.getSheetByName("Liste de Bouttons")  
var rangeUSER = sheetBoutons.getRange(4, 2)
var rangeUSER2 = sheetBoutons.getRange(4, 3)
var USER = rangeUSER.getValues();



    switch(USER) {
      case 'Afficher-INV1':
        sheetINV.hideColumns(1,183);
        sheetINV.showColumns(22);
        sheetINV.showColumns(24);      
        rangeUSER2.setValue(rangeUSER.getValue());
        rangeUSER.clearContent();
        break;

    default: 
    break
    }}
```

There are way more cases to add but that would just be visual pollution right now. 
any help is appreciated,

Comment: It looks like you've done good research on switch statements, and I don't see anything wrong at the code level. If this isn't working, it could be due to something that we can't see from the question itself. For example, does a method named `getValues` really return a string? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess, this code is JavaScript, using Google Spreadsheets.

[`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) returns an array of arrays of values. This incidentally stringifies to the cell's value (due to length-1 arrays not adding any cruft). But `switch` statements in JavaScript compare with strict "`===`" equality ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Description)), in which `[['abc']] === 'abc'` is false.

The documentation for `getValues` (linked above) shows an example that indexes into the result. I would see if `switch (USER[0][0]) { ... }` helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
switch (n)
{
    case constant1:
        // code to be executed if n is equal to constant1;
        break;

    case constant2:
        // code to be executed if n is equal to constant2;
        break;
        .
        .
        .
    default:
        // code to be executed if n doesn't match any constant
}
```

Similarly, for your code, It can be like:

```
 switch (USER) {
      case 'Afficher-INV1':
        sheetINV.hideColumns(1,183);
        sheetINV.showColumns(22);
        sheetINV.showColumns(24);      
        rangeUSER2.setValue(rangeUSER.getValue());
        rangeUSER.clearContent();
        break;

      case 'Afficher-INV2':
        sheetINV.hideColumns(1,183);
        sheetINV.showColumns(22);
        sheetINV.showColumns(24);      
        rangeUSER3.setValue(rangeUSER.getValue());
        rangeUSER.clearContent();
        break;

    default: rangeUSER.clearContent();
    }
```